# html img structure varying on input

Tags: jsoup

When i add below lines of code in the javascript the img ending tag gets disappeared

```
Jsoup = org.jsoup.Jsoup;
doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Source Data :

```
<div class="col-sm-3"><a title="Microsemi's Ultra-secure SmartFusion2 SoC FPGAs and IGLOO2 FPGAs Recognized on EDN's List of Hot 100 Products of 2014" href="http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/microsemis-ultra-secure-smartfusion2-soc-fpgas-and-igloo2-fpgas-recognized-on-edns-list-of-hot-100-products-of-2014-300010576.html" ><img class="list-image" src="http://photos.prnewswire.com/prnthumb/20110909/MM66070LOGO" border="0" alt="Microsemi Corporation." id="img0" /></a></div>
```

Target Data Which i got by appling above two lines :

```
<div class="col-sm-3"> 
     <a title="Microsemi's Ultra-secure SmartFusion2 SoC FPGAs and IGLOO2 FPGAs Recognized on EDN's List of Hot 100 Products of 2014" href="http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/microsemis-ultra-secure-smartfusion2-soc-fpgas-and-igloo2-fpgas-recognized-on-edns-list-of-hot-100-products-of-2014-300010576.html"> <img src="http://photos.prnewswire.com/prnthumb/20110909/MM66070LOGO" alt="Microsemi Corporation."> </a> 
    </div>
```

Any suggestions how to resolve it. In the above target img ending tag is missing. So how could i resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-3"><a title="Microsemi's Ultra-secure SmartFusion2 SoC FPGAs and IGLOO2 FPGAs Recognized on EDN's List of Hot 100 Products of 2014" href="http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/microsemis-ultra-secure-smartfusion2-soc-fpgas-and-igloo2-fpgas-recognized-on-edns-list-of-hot-100-products-of-2014-300010576.html" >

<img id="img0" class="list-image" src="http://photos.prnewswire.com/prnthumb/20110909/MM66070LOGO" border="0" alt="Microsemi Corporation."/></a></div>
```

Comment: I want to know why this is happened when parsing html file. You have specified the modified image ending tag. But I want to know how can i do it using jsoup